# Why To Use Transmission Queue

Tags: ibm-mq

Why we use Transmission queue to store message in Sending a message to remote queue as we can also store the message in local queue.
So creating a transmission queue is taking memory and space.

Answer (score 6):

You need to learn more about MQ.  A good place to start is the [MQ Primer](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp0021.pdf).

You will learn that a transmission queue (aka XMITQ) is a local queue that is used by the MCA (Message Channel Agent) to transfer messages from the local queue manager to the remote queue manager.  Messages should only be in the XMITQ very briefly.